# Using SimpleChanges to access multiple properties

Tags: angular

What would be the best way to rewrite the following ngOnChanges lifecycle hook as a SimpleChanges derivative? I haven't seen examples where the data-bound properties are all dependent on each other.

```
export class BuilderSidebarPhotosComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() photos: IUnsplashResponse[];
  @Input() photosLoaded = false;
  @Input() photoCategories: IPhotoCategory[];
  @Input() photoCategoriesLoaded = false;
  @Input() activeSetting = null;
  @Input() innerHeight;

  PHOTOS_LISTING_INNER_HEIGHT_OFFSET = 200;

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.photosListingInnerHeight = this.innerHeight - this.PHOTOS_LISTING_INNER_HEIGHT_OFFSET;
    if (
      this.photoCategoriesLoaded === true &&
      this.photosLoaded === true &&
      this.activeSetting === ActiveSettings.Photos
    ) {
      this.setInitialLoader();
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in this case only some of the properties depend to each other, one solution would be change them to setters individually and call the check function each time they change. Ex.:

```
...
@Input() set photosLoaded(value) {
   ...
   this.checkIfInitialStateIsReady();
   ...
};
...
```